# Get meta data via "woocommerce_order_get_formatted_billing_address" filter hook

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, metadata, hook-woocommerce

Im trying to apply a custom post meta field `billing_company_id` to **orders formatterd billing address**, and place it below billing company.

Via the following code I can apply a string but how to get the custom post meta from an order?

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_get_formatted_billing_address', 'company_billing_id', 20, 1 );
function company_billing_id($address){
    $address .= 'Custom field string'; 
    return $address;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `woocommerce_order_get_formatted_billing_address` filter hook contains not 1 but 3 parameters.

Via the 3rd you have access to the `$order` object, so you could use something like:

```php
/**
 * Filter orders formatterd billing address.
 *
 * @since 3.8.0
 * @param string   $address     Formatted billing address string.
 * @param array    $raw_address Raw billing address.
 * @param WC_Order $order       Order data. @since 3.9.0
 */
function filter_woocommerce_order_get_formatted_billing_address( $address, $raw_address, $order ) {
    // Get meta
    $value = $order->get_meta( 'billing_company_id' );

    // NOT empty
    if ( ! empty ( $value ) ) {
        // Append
        $address .= $value;
    }

    return $address;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_get_formatted_billing_address', 'filter_woocommerce_order_get_formatted_billing_address', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: Thanks  I managed to solve it myself in the meanwhile.
U hav small typing error 
$adress .= $value;   ->  $a**d**dress .= $value;